# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a script in trigger to insert the audit table if any update happens on T_Referral table and i am using a Decrypt function to Decrypt the data in one of the column. My code in trigger is :

```
DECLARE @Sql_Insert nvarchar(max)
SET @Sql_Insert = ''
SET @Sql_Insert='INSERT INTO [Logg].AuditLogData(TableName, ColumnName, OldValue, OldValue_Decode, NewValue, NewValue_Decode, AuditSubCategoryID,[GuID])
select TableName, ColumnName, OldValue_Decode, case when ColumnName = ''BookingUserReferenceValue'' then utl.sfDecrypt(NewValue,0) Else NewValue end, NewValue_Decode, AuditSubCategoryID,[GuID] from #AuditLogData
where ISNULL(OldValue,'') != ISNULL([NewValue],'')'

exec utl.uspOpenOrCloseEncryptionKey 'open'
exec(@Sql_Insert )
exec utl.uspOpenOrCloseEncryptionKey 'close'
```

---

My update script is

```
Update RTS.T_Referral   
set BookingUserReferenceValue =  cast ('John Wayne' as varbinary(256))
where ReferralId = 20
```

I am Updating the record to `John Wayne` as varbinary in `T_Referral` table(record looks like `0x4A6F686E205761796E65`) and when update trigger is called it would load that record as John Wayne in Audit table. When the record is inserted in BookingUserReferenceValue it will be encrypted. The datatype of column BookingUserReferenceValue is Varbinary(256). when i try to update the record in that column i get error :

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near ')'.

Any Idea whats wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Are utl.sfDecrypt(NewValue,0) and NewValue of the same datatype?

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the single quotes:

```
SET @Sql_Insert='
INSERT INTO [Logg].AuditLogData(TableName, ColumnName, OldValue, OldValue_Decode, NewValue, NewValue_Decode, AuditSubCategoryID,[GuID])
select 
    TableName, ColumnName, OldValue, OldValue_Decode, 
    case when ColumnName = ''BookingUserReferenceValue'' then utl.sfDecrypt(NewValue,0) Else NewValue end,
    NewValue_Decode, AuditSubCategoryID,[GuID] 
from #AuditLogData
where 
    ISNULL(OldValue, cast('''' as varbinary(256))) != 
    ISNULL([NewValue], cast('''' as varbinary(256)))
';
```

Comment: I am getting error Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: @mike I guess it is just the lack of casting. Edited.

Comment: i tried using convert too in update script but it throws same error

Comment: Is OldValue missing in your SELECT list?

Comment: It wasn't just your error.  It was an error in the original post.  Maybe that's the cause of the error.

Comment: @mike Check if GilM's hint fixes it.

Comment: Hi, i have two many columns in there so i just selected few of them . i have correct column in in my trigger but giving the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If we write non-boolean expression in `IF` statement, `WHERE` clause, `HAVING` clause etc it is comes under syntax error. Please check your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think OldValue is missing from your SELECT list.  I'm not sure why you didn't get the error that the number of columns didn't match.

Comment: That is sure an error. But I guess first it tries to execute the select and gets stuck by two errors: First the lack of quote escaping. Second the lack of casting.